# This activity loads very slowly, takes about 10-15 seconds to load

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

This is my activity in android and it takes too long to load. Please give me an alternative way which can make it faster. This code is in my onCreate() method.

```
    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();

    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("1");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("0");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post `checkBTState()`? I'm guessing it's a blocking function.

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html to profile method calls